# Custom UITableView Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it possible to change the scrolling on a UITableView? Such as the following?

http://dribbble.com/shots/1176252-Events-iOS7?list=users

In this example, the cells have an accordion effect to them. It's like when the user drags a cell from the top of the page down the ones underneath the dragged location pinch into it, and the ones above it pull away.

I feel like I could do this if I were just use UIView's as cells and custom animate them but I believe that I would be wasting so much making a ton of UIViews.

Any tips, or direction would be so helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the new API's for iOS 7 you should be able to do it with that :-) UIKit dynamics is what you should look for in the dev center.

Comment: I'm having problems location documentation on iOS 7 UIKit dynamics, could you post a link perhaps?

Comment: You should be able to find it here. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013154